# MVC regex to not allow spaces and special characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Regex to not allow spaces and some special chars., but the validation fires even when Uppercase letters are entered.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[^<>.,?;:'()!~%-_@#%/*""\s]+$")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the `-` (minus sign). `%-_` means between `%` (char code 37) and `_` (char code 95) which includes upper case characters.

If you want to exclude the minus symbol, then you need to escape it using `\-`.

The attribute should be

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[^<>.,?;:'()!~%\-_@#/*""\s]+$")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```